# Best practices for coding simple mathematical calculations in Python

Tags: math, coding-style, python, python-2.7

I need to perform simple mathematical calculations in Python 2.7 with sums, subtractions, divisions, multiplications, sums over lists of numbers etc.

I want to write elegant, bullet-proof, and efficient code but I must admit I got confused by several things, for example:

- if I have `1/(N-1)*x` in my equation should I just code `1/(N-1)*x` or maybe `1.0/(N-1)*x`, `1.0/(N-1.0)*x` or any other combination of these?
- for division, should I use `//` or `/` with `from __future__ import division`?
- what practices such as "using `math.fsum()` for concatenating a list of floats" are out there?
- should I assume that input numbers are float or do the conversion just in case (maybe risking drop of efficiency on many `float(x)` operations)?

So what are the best practices for writing a code for simple mathematical calculations in Python that is

1. elegant/Pythonic,
2. efficient,
3. bullet-proof to issues like uncertainty in exact number type of input data (float vs integer) ?

Comment: I'd just use `x/(N-1.0)` - one float is enough to contaminate everything, and there's one useless operation cut down (`*1.0`). You would never use `//` for non-integral division.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. If you use Python 2.7, **ALWAYS** use `from __future__ import division`. It removes a hell of a lot confusion and bugs.

   With this you should never have to worry if a division is a float or not, `/` will always be a float and `//` will always be an int.
2. You should convert your input with `float()`. You will do it only once, and it won't be much of a performance hit.
3. I would get the sum of a list of floats like this: `sum(li, 0.0)`, but if precision is required, use `math.fsum` which is specifically created for this.
4. And finally, your final statement was confusing. Did you mean `1/((N-1)*x)` or `(1/(N-1))*x`? In the first case I would write it as `1 / (x * (N-1))` and in the second case `x / (N-1)`. Both assume 3.x style division.

Also, look into numpy if you want some real performance.

Comment: Actually I meant `(1/(N-1))*x`. I haven't written is as `x / (N-1)` as it was generalization of some bigger equation where `x` was sth more complicated and it was clearer to write it this way ;-)

Comment: +1 for `numpy`. Get `scipy` and `matplotlib` installed as well, if math is your poison of choice.

Answer (score 2):

If you want great performance for numerical code in Python, you should consider PyPy. Numpy and scipy are convenient for dealing with arrays, and they give good performance if you use linear algebra algorithms that they provide. But if your numerical operations are in pure Python code, PyPy can give significant improvements in performance. I have seen speedups above 20x. And when you use PyPy, the best way to write your mathematical expressions is the simplest way. It will optimize your code better than you could, so make it as simple and readable as possible.